# Typescript type error while destructuring on empty object with default values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm writing a web application in ReactJS + Typescript. I've a functional component defined like below. 
 My problem is the following: in the props, for the property `exercise`, the parent component is passing an object, either initialized empty or of a certain type that I specify, `Exercise`. Then Typescript raises the following errors:

`[ts] Property 'description' does not exist on type '{} | Exercise'`
`[ts] Property 'title' does not exist on type '{} | Exercise'`

How could I refactor it so that if the object is indeed empty, it will use the default values, and otherwise, use the values passed?

**EDIT: Added the other props that I use**

```
type Exercise = {
  description: string
  id: string
  muscles: string
  title: string
}

type Props = {
  category: string
  children?: never
  exercise: {} | Exercise
  exercises: Array<[string, Exercise[]]>
  onSelect: (id: string) => void
}

const Exercises = ({
  exercises,
  category,
  onSelect,
  exercise: {
    description = 'Please select an exercise',
    title = 'Welcome!'
  }
}: Props) => (
   <Grid container>
     <Grid item sm>
       {/* Some stuff going on with exercises, category and onSelect */ }
     </Grid>
     <Grid item sm>
       <Paper>
         <Typography variant="h4">{title}</Typography>
         <Typography variant="subtitle1">{description}</Typography>
       </Paper>
     </Grid>
   </Grid>
)
```

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So overall I don't think your API design is correct for this component. You're basically misusing exercise entity as some default "Welcome message stuff", which is rather miss leading to consumers of this component.

What I would do, is to provide these intro defaults when there is no exercise present, but would definitely not use exercise prop to assign those defaults.

Next thing, don't use `{}`, that's not empty object (you can define empty object like following https://github.com/Hotell/rex-tils/blob/master/src/guards/types.ts#L39 ) . It used to be a bottom type prior to TS 3.0 ( now `unknown` is bottom type ). What does it mean? `{}` can be anything except null/undefined:

```
// all of this is valid !
let foo: {} = 1231
foo = true
foo = { baz: 'bar' }
foo = [1,2,3]
```

Also if you really wanna support passing "empty" non primitive data types to components, prefer `null`:

```
type Props = {
  category: string
  children?: never
  // Maybe type
  exercise: null | Exercise
  exercises: [string, Exercise[]][]
  onSelect: (id: string) => void
}
```

---

Anyways if your really wanna keep your API as is. You have following option:

1. Extract defaults to constant which needs to be cast to Exercise

```
const defaultExercise = {
  description: 'Please select an exercise',
  title: 'Welcome!',
} as Exercise
```

2. you need to type narrow exercise prop outside function default parameter, as that's not possible within function params

```
const Exercises = ({ exercises, category, onSelect, exercise }: Props) => {
  // $ExpectType Exercise
  const { title, description } = exercise ? exercise : defaultExercise

  return <>your markup</>
}
```

Now while this works it gives you false assumptions. As your `exercise` might be a partial one (if defaults are used), which may lead to runtime errors. You'll need additional type narrowing via guards ( if, ternary ).

You can improve this situation on type level, by some type mappings:

```
// $ExpectType  { description: string, title: string, id?: string, muscles?: string }
const defaultExercise = {
  description: 'Please select an exercise',
  title: 'Welcome!',
} as Partial<Exercise> & Required<Pick<Exercise, 'description' | 'title'>>
```

With that type if you would use `id` or `muscles` within your component, you'll get proper types as they might be undefined, which mirrors correctly our ternary

```
const { 
  title, //$ExpectType string 
  description, //$ExpectType string
  id, //$ExpectType string | undefined  
} = exercise ? exercise : defaultExercise
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I refactored this component and what the parent was passing! This `Partial<Exercise> & Required<Pick<Exercise, 'description' | 'title'>>` was definitely what I had in mind, but as a TS begginer, I couldn't find the proper syntax. The destructuring with ternary values to assign defaults is a really neat solution. Thumbs up!

Comment: Don't you think that having both `null` and `undefined` available in JavaScript can lead to confusion? I read about it from TSLint documentation: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-null-keyword/ I would like to hear more opinions on this subject to identify good practices...

Answer (score 3):

I think something similar to this should work

```
type Exercise = {
  description: string
  id: string
  muscles: string
  title: string
}

type Props = {
  exercise: Partial<Exercise>
}

const Exercises = (props: Props) => {
    const exercice = {
      description:'Please select an exercise',
      title: 'Welcome!', 
      ...props.exercise
    }

    return (
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item sm>
            <Paper>
              <Typography variant="h4">{exercice.title}</Typography>
              <Typography variant="subtitle1">{exercice.description}</Typography>
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

edit: align code

Comment: You could add explicitly the type on exercise.

Comment: const exercice: Exercice = { description:'Please select an exercise', title: 'Welcome!', ...props }

Comment: I fixed it to support other props

Comment: I'd still be curious to know if I can type my `exercise` prop to be strictly an empty object, or an object with all the types I defined as required. Something more precise an object with optional properties.

Comment: My solution so far is to keep the `Partial<Exercise>` on the type definition of `props`. Then, in the body of my component, I destructure my other props like so `const { exercises, category, onSelect } = props`. To access and type the `exercise` prop, I use your solution, adding a `Partial<Exercise>` type on the object.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Especially since **it actually works**, whereas @hotell's one doesn't (at least not for me). +1! :D